# How to fetch emails those are not stored in our database using php imap

Tags: php, imap, php-imap

I am working on vtiger CRM module for fetching emails from mail server using php imap with different applied conditions.

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}';
$username = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$password = 'mypswd';

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());  
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'FROM from@gmail.com');

if($emails) {

    $output = '';

    rsort($emails);

    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);
        $message = trim(quoted_printable_decode($message));
        $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
        $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
        $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
        $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
        $output.= '</div>';
        $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
        echo $output;die;
    }

    echo $output;
}
```

This complete code is working fine, but want to fetch only new emails those are not stored into my database yet, so that once an email is stored in my database it should not be stored again.

Comment: you could filter on the date

Comment: or get emails from db in array and compare your imap email array (difference)

Comment: but in this case i can fetch only once for a day, but i want to run cron job after each 3 mins, so that it would keep updating my records.

Comment: is there any way like if i store any email in my database i store it with its unique email id and i only fetch emails with unique id greater then that Id ?

Comment: If you use UIDs and fetch from the lowest to highest, all newer messages will have higher UIDs.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved, I filtered using date parameter so that it fetch minimum emails, and i stored message_id in to my database and using this message_id i put a condition if it already exists or not in my database.